# Show that the closed $n$-ball $B^n(a)$ is a manifold

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, manifolds-with-boundary

> Show that the closed $n$-ball $B^n(a)$ is a manifold.

I know how to show that $S^{n-1}(a)=\partial B^n(a)$ is an $n-1$ manifold without boundary. We consider the function $f(x)=a^2-\Vert x\Vert ^2$. And the open ball $B^n(a)$ is trivially an $n$-dimensional manifold, since it is open in $\mathbb R^n$. But how about the closed ball? I cannot use the same function as for $S^{n-1}(a)$, because $\det Df(0)=0$, so we have a problem there. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The closed ball isn't a manifold. It's a manifold *with boundary* (i.e. locally diffeomorphic to an open subset of the closed half-space), but not a manifold itself (i.e. locally diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$).

Comment: My book denotes a manifold with boundary as manifold, and a manifold as manifold without boundary.

Comment: How you want to prove it ? By definition or by showing that it is a regular level set of some function ? I've working this out by constructing the explicit homeomorphism (and i think i got it).  For the former see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313700/showing-that-bar-mathbbbn-is-a-manifold-with-boundary-lee-itm-probelm-3/2755562#2755562) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031257/show-that-mathbbbn-is-a-smooth-manifold-with-its-boundary-diffeomorphic-t?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the later

Comment: @Sou Thanks. I'm not familiar with the notion of regular value yet, but I guess I will be after I've had some more topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need to show that every point $x \in  B^n(a)$ has a neighborhood $U$ which  is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{H}^n = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \ | \ x_n \geq 0\}$. This is the *upper half space*, and has boundary $\{(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \ | \ x_n = 0\}$. The points $x$ which are mapped to the boundary of $\mathbb{H}^n$ by the above-described homeomorphism form the *boundary* of the manifold.

Since clearly each point $x$ in the *interior* of $B^n(a)$ has a neighborhood  which is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{H}^n$ (just by, say, translating a small  ball around $x$ upwards so that now it lies in the upper half plane).

So the only issue is showing that each point on the boundary $S^{n - 1}$ has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to an open neighborhood of $\mathbb{H}^n$. This can be done by "straightening the boundary" of the sphere. To do this, try  using stereographic  projection (see https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/closed-ball-is-manifold-with-boundary.744620/).

It would probably help to do  this  in 2 dimensions first; the generalization step should be almost identical.